# AngularJS app with no URL's / deeplinking

Tags: angularjs, navigation, location

How do you navigate views/partials without changing URL/route? I want only one single URL so that there is no browser history back/next.

I tried UI-Route, what basically does what i want, but as soon as i'm on a view with an $apply method the address bar changes from 'someapp.com' to 'someapp.com/#/'. It occurs in angular 1.1.5, but not 1.0.7 and only in hashbang mode. How do i get rid of this URL change?

Thank you!

Edit: i could sort the issue out and now use ui-router for that task.

Answer (score 2):

You can control everything without routes. But if you want multiple controllers, you'll have to broadcast shared events. My example uses a nested controller approach.

View:

```
<div ng-controller="mainCtrl">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills">
        <li ng-class="{active: activeView.view1}">
            <a href="javascript:" ng-click="setView('view1')"> View1 </a>
        </li>
        <li ng-class="{active: activeView.view2}">
            <a href="javascript:" ng-click="setView('view2')"> View2 </a>
        </li>
        <li ng-class="{active: activeView.view3}">
            <a href="javascript:" ng-click="setView('view3')"> View3 </a>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <div>
        <div ng-show="activeView.view1">
            <div ng-controller="view1Ctrl">
            ....
            </div>
        </div>
        <div ng-show="activeView.view2">
            <div ng-controller="view2Ctrl">
            ....
            </div>
        </div>
        <div ng-show="activeView.view3">
            <div ng-controller="view3Ctrl">
            ....
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then in the mainCtrl:

```
//Handles the main view set function and broadcasts down to sub-controllers
$scope.setView = function(view) {
    $scope.activeView = {
        view1: false,
        view2: false,
        view3: false
    }
    $scope.activeView[view] = true;
    $scope.$broadcast('setView', view);
};

//Catches the reset view call from sub-controllers and re-broadcasts down
$scope.$on('viewReset', function(scope, view, msg) {
    $scope.setView(view, msg);
})
```

And in the subCtrls:

```
//Catches the broadcast down and sets vars locally.
$scope.$on('setView', function(scope, view) {
    $scope.activeView = {
        view1: false,
        view2: false,
        view3: false
    }
    $scope.activeView[view] = true;
});

//Emits the message up to the mainCtrl to reset the view in all controllers
$scope.setView = function(view) {
    $scope.$emit('setView', view);
};
```

Comment: Thank you, nice solution! I thought of something similar with ngSwitch. But in my case i have to instantiate the views dynamically and are therefore not able to put all views in one html document. Currently i think state based would be most adequate.